# Joining Information from Point and Polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-joins

I tried to find the answer to this question by searching, but I was not too successful. My issue is that I have a point file of around 400 Organizations that do not have a column of county names tied to them. I also have a polygon shapefile of all counties in the United States. I selected the counties that all had an organization located within them, and now I want to give each organization the name of the County that they are located in. How would I go about doing this? I attempted a Join but was unsuccessful; both attribute columns have the same name and data type.

Comment: can you post the what attributes do the files have so that it is clear how the data reference each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this using a [spatial join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000), or the [intersect tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000z000000). Spatial join will allow you to retain all features regardless of whether they intersect the second feature class, intersect will create a new feature class with only those features that intersect.